# R - Deleting both rows in a "paired" dataframe if one value = x

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where every two rows is part of a choice set - which will be used for discrete choice analysis in mlogit. I want to delete all rows associated with a choice set, based on the values in a column.

For example - with this simple data set, lets say I wanted to remove all the pairs where there was a yellow value in one of the rows in a pair (pairs defined here by "Set").

I am assuming there must be an easy way to say if this value = "x" , and this value of this other column matches the value of that row, remove both. I'm figuring it must be something to do with ifelse or case_when in dplyr, but its the matching value part that I'm not sure about. In excel I would use a cell reference to do a simple if_then, but not sure the best way to do that in R. Thanks!

```
data <-  data.frame(Set = sort(rep(1:20,2)), 
                    Choice = rep(c(T,F),20),
                    Color = sample(
                      rep(c("Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"),5)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select those `set` which has all the values in `Color` column which not `'Yellow'`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(all(Color != 'Yellow'))
```

Or another way to write this would be :

```
data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(!any(Color == 'Yellow'))
```

---

This can also be written in base R

```
subset(data, ave(Color != 'Yellow', Set, FUN = all))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(Color != 'Yellow')], Set]
```

Comment: Awesome - add on , if I wanted to filter by two variables , would it work to do 
```data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(!any(Color == 'Yellow'| Color == 'Blue"))```

Comment: Yes, that would work. Also you can use `%in%` : `data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(!any(Color %in% c('Yellow', 'Blue')))`

Comment: Brilliant - even better, in practice I will be filtering out a few values so that's even more concise, thank you

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a need to do a calculation for each group as such. You can find the `Set`s containing `"Yellow"`, then only keep those that aren't in those `Set`s. Since we're talking sets, let's use some set theory:

```
data[data$Set %in% setdiff(data$Set, data$Set[data$Color == "Yellow"]),]
```

You can expand this to many colours easily:

```
data[data$Set %in% setdiff(data$Set, data$Set[data$Color %in% c("Yellow","Green")]),]
```

And why should you care? Because if you ever work with large datasets with many groups, doing all the calculations in a single pass is a lot faster then having to repeat everything for each group:

```
## one million groups!
data <- data[rep(1:20, each=1e5),]
data$Set <- rep(1:1e6, each=2)

library(dplyr)
system.time({ 
    data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(all(Color != 'Yellow'))
})
## i'm still waiting for this to finish 10 minutes later

system.time({
    data[data$Set %in% setdiff(data$Set, data$Set[data$Color == "Yellow"]),]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.301   0.000   0.302
```

Comment: Thanks for the added justification on why use this method over the dplyr method. In cases where data is smaller and the code is being shared with folks who otherwise are not familiar with the process (nor need to be) - I like dplyr because of the ease of readability. But in practice, when large datasets are in play - your method is clearly superior.

Answer (score 2):

```
df[!(df$Set %in% with(df, Set[which(Color == "Yellow")])),]
```